# jQuery Ajax fileDownload not posting data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I wrote the following ajax code which calls an export.php file, but since I cannot initate the file to download, i've used jQuery fileDownload which is working nicely and pops up my file download. However, my original ajax code was able to post all my form data to the export.php file. The new fileDownload ajax code does not seem to post any data to export.php.

Can anyone advise? i tried changing $(this).serialize() to $('#loginForm').serialize() but still no luck

Original Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'export.php', 
    cache:false,
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
    success:
        function (data) {
            var responseCode = parseInt(data);
        }
});
```

fileDownload ajax code:

```
$.fileDownload('export.php?'+ Math.random(), {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    successCallback: function (url) {
        $(pleaseWait).remove();
    },
    failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
        $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
        $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true });
    }
});
```

Comment: why don't you try with $('#loginForm') instead of this.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I tried that, but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out why the $.fileDownload method wasn't posting data. I tried changing $(this).serialize to $('#loginForm') although this worked with $.ajax it didnt work with the $.fileDownload, so i changed it to $(form).serialize and it now works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin is not compatible with FormData.

Answer (score 0):

There are few required things and you will get file on Postback.

Make sure that **form** tag contains  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

**Like:**

```
<form id="frm1" method="POST" action="export.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   .... //your input fields and input file.
</form>
```

**Ajax** should be like:

```
            var formData = new FormData($("#frm1")[0]);
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: actionURL,
                data:formData, //$(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
},
                error: function (err) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
```

I hope this will help you. Its just a demo you can set it as per your requirements.

Comment: problem with this way is that it's similar to the ajax way I already got working in the first example, but I need to get it working with the $.fileDownload method instead of the $.ajax method.

Comment: Please consider the first line of my JS code. `var formData = new FormData($("#frm1")[0]);`

Comment: Using this line, I hope so that you will able to post file.